# Доступ к проводному принтеру через wifi на ноутбуке

Tags: windows, wifi, принтер

В офисе стоит несколько пк и один обычный проводной юсб принтер. Чтобы пользоваться приходится каждый раз перетыкать кабель между компами.
Появилась идея, использовать один из ноутбуков, как сервер для сетевого принтера. Чтобы при подключении к этой сети можно было без проблем печатать из любого устройства. Возможно ли такое вообще?

Comment: Да, это возможно. Просто нужно сделать принтер доступным по сети в настройках. А можно взять роутер, который умеет принтсервер.

Comment: @koVadim, расскажите подробней о настройках. И возможно ли будет с телефона печатать?

Comment: Поставить галочку в настройках принтера, что он доступен по сети? С телефона - не знаю, может это Nokia 3310

Comment: @KoVadim, я открыл доступ для сети, но походу этого мало

Comment: @Somonator на другом компе пуск-выполнить `\\имякомпа\` потом правой кнопкой - подключить